# How to deal with fn.call(this) replacing original this

Tags: javascript

To begin, I have an application that is used for managing employees. When the user creates a new instance of the application, I would like for them to have an option to submit a function that will run before anything else in the application does. The problem is that I need to add functionality to the end of that function so I need it passed back to the application.

However, if I use `fn.call(this)` in the `StateManager.js` class, it then overrides the `this` of state manager and gets rid of the functionality of `StateManager`. The exact error returned is `Uncaught TypeError: this.onPreload is not a function`

Essentially, when a new instance is created, I would like to take the user's `preload` function and pass it to `StateManager.js` where it will be adjusted.

Here is demonstration code:

```js
class Application {

  constructor(options = {}) {
    return new User(options);
  }
}

class User {

  constructor(options) {
    this._options = options;
    this.state = new StateManager(this);
    this.job = new Job(this);
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.state.onPreload = this._options.preload;
    this.state.preload.call(this);
  }
}

class Job {

  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  changeTitle(title) {
    this.user.jobTitle = title;
  }
}

class StateManager {

  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.onPreload = null;
  }

  preload() {
    this.onPreload();
  }
}

const options = {
  preload: preload
};

const app = new Application(options);

function preload() {
  app.job.changeTitle('CEO');
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { Application } from './Application.js';

const options = {
    preload: preload
};

const app = new Application(options);

function preload() {
    // Access some irrelevant function in job that sets a new value
    app.job.changeTitle('CEO');
}
```

**app.js**

```
import { User } from './User.js';

export class Application {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        return new User(options);
    }
}
```

**user.js**

```
import { StateManager } from './StateManager.js';
import { Job } from './Job.js';

export class User {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this._options = options;
        this.state = new StateManager(this);
        this.job = new Job(this);

        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.state.onPreload = this._options.preload;
        this.state.preload.call(this);
    }
}
```

**statemanager.js**

```
export class StateManager {
    constructor(user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.onPreload = null;
    }

    preload() {
        this.onPreload();

        // My custom functionality to add at the end.
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you use anything like *`fn.call(this)` in the `StateManager.js`* - perhaps you should *show the code you're having problems with* - since you have no function called `fn` it's hard to *guess what you are talking about*

Comment: `where it will be adjusted` - what does this even mean?

Comment: Why are you doing this at all, though? Why are you using `this.state.preload.call(this);` instead of just `this.state.preload(this);` with the preload function accepting an argument `preload(app) { /* use app.whatever here */ }`?

Comment: @JaromandaX the `fn.call(this)` is referring to any function but in my case it would be in the User class where I call `this.state.preload.call(this)`;

Comment: Just use `this.state.preload()`, there's no need to use `.call()`.

Comment: @Barmar I try that but then it says that user is unknown

Comment: Where does that error happen, `this.user = user`? I don't see how that could be unknown, since it's a function parameter.

Comment: It's not clear how everything is related here, but I suspect what you need is something like `this.onPreload.call(this.user);`

Comment: @Bamar I'm sorry I meant that `app` is not defined. Here is the exact error I get in the Chrome dev console.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at StateManager.preload [as onPreload] ((index))
    at StateManager.preload (State.js)`

Comment: Or maybe `this.state.onPreload = this._options.preload.bind(this);`

Comment: `app` is a global variable, it shouldn't have anything to do with `this`.

Comment: @Barmar I have added a jsfiddle demonstrating this example. If you look at the console you can see the original error I get and if you apply the changes you suggested and run it, you will see the `app is not defined` error I mentioned.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to use `app` before you've assigned it. `new Application()` eventually calls `preload()`, `preload()` tries to use `app`, but this is all happening in the expression used to initialize `app`.

Comment: It's just a complex version of `const app = someFunc(); function someFunc() { return app + 1; }`

Comment: @Barmar I understand it now. Is there a proposed solution to that? Do I have to create an event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preload()` is referring to the global variable `app`, but it's being called in the function used to initialize `app` in the first place. It needs to receive the `User` object being initialized, rather than referring to the global variable.

Use `this.state.onPreload = this._options.preload.bind(this);` to bind the context of the `preload` function to that object.

You could also change `StateManager.preload()` to use `this.onPreload.call(this.user);`. But this might create an inappropriate dependency that doesn't apply in all cases. If I understood all the relationships better, I might be able to decide this better.

```js
class Application {

  constructor(options = {}) {
    return new User(options);
  }
}

class User {

  constructor(options) {
    this._options = options;
    this.state = new StateManager(this);
    this.job = new Job(this);
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.state.onPreload = this._options.preload.bind(this);
    this.state.preload();
  }
}

class Job {

  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  changeTitle(title) {
    this.user.jobTitle = title;
  }
}

class StateManager {

  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.onPreload = null;
  }

  preload() {
    this.onPreload();
  }
}

const options = {
  preload: preload
};

const app = new Application(options);
console.log(app.jobTitle);

function preload() {
  this.job.changeTitle('CEO');
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm but I just have one question, is there any way to use `app.job.changeTitle` instead of `this.job.changeTitle`? The use of `this` might confuse some users as this app will end up being super high level so even non-programmers can use it fairly easily.

Comment: No, there's no way to use a variable in the code that's initializing the variable in the first place. Maybe you can split it into two steps: First initialize the variable, then call a method on it that calls `preload()`.